# docker: Error response from daemon: Address already in use

Tags: docker

I am creating a container with following command

```
docker run -it -p 81:80 -p 3307:3306 --net mynet123 --ip 172.18.0.22 -v /opt/lampp/htdocs:/var/www/html lamp-setia bash
```

Can Someone share the solution?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the existing port by running command

```
lsof -i tcp:81
```

and

```
lsof -i tcp:3307
```

if necessary you can kill that process with command

```
kill -9 [pid number]
```

After that, you can try to re-run that docker command.

Answer (score 6):

Another scenario that have the exact same error is when the IP address is in use. In my setup, I had a network setup like this:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.28.5.0/24 cluster-test-net
```

and I was trying to start my docker container as below:

```
docker run -d --name wildfly1 --ip 172.28.5.1 -h wildfly1 -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 --network=cluster-test-net wildfly-cluster-image
```

The reason that I got the error was that docker had already assigned the IP address `172.28.5.1` to the host itself. I noticed that when I ran `ifconfig` on my host and found this row in the result:

```
br-bb89994f6a73: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.5.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.28.5.255
        inet6 fe80::42:a2ff:fecd:81e9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:a2:cd:81:e9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4394  bytes 4695729 (4.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2342  bytes 175071 (175.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So I just fixed it by choosing a different IP address for my docker container:

```
docker run -d --name wildfly1 --ip 172.28.5.10 -h wildfly1 -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 --network=cluster-test-net wildfly-cluster-image
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems that some other process is already holding the host ports that you are trying to map with the container. You may consider using `netstat -aon` to find out if there is/are existing processses that are holding ports **81** and **3307** on the docker host.

Answer (score 3):

The port you have given in the docker run command might be assigned to some other process. Please find what is running over there. If something unimportant  kill it. Or you can proceed with available ports.

Please find a snapshot below for reference,
[image]

Regards

Answer (score 2):

this means another container is taking the container's IP.
Stop all containers and then start your container.
then start your container :

```
docker stop x
docker network connect --ip  172.24.0.4  yournetwork  y
docker start y
docker start x
```

The order would tell indicate the conflicting containers

or use container network `docker inspect network_name`
to check whether the containers have the correct Ips